# Performance warning for isspace function, conversion from int to bool

Tags: c++, if-statement, type-conversion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

bool notSpace(char c) {
    return !isspace(c);
}
bool isSpace(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}
vector<string> split(const string& s) {
    vector<string> words;
    string::const_iterator i = s.begin();
    while (i != s.end()) {
        i = find_if(i, s.end(), notSpace); // "              "
        if (i != s.end()) {
            string::const_iterator j = i;
            j = find_if(i, s.end(), isSpace);
            words.push_back(string(i, j));
            i = j;
        }
    }
    return words;
}
int main() {
    string test = "Hello world, I'm a simple guy";
    vector<string> words = split(test);
    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < words.size();i++) {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code I get this warning:

> warning C4800: 'int': forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'
>   (performance warning)

on the return of this function:

```
bool isSpace(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}
```

Is good habit changing `isspace(c)` to `(isspace(c) != 0)` ? Or is it just an unnecessary fussiness?

Comment: Why do you need the functions at all?

Comment: The compiler is telling you that it is basically doing what you have suggested (to convert the int return to a bool).  So in my opinion you might as well add the code to shut-up the warning.

Comment: You'll gain a great deal *more* by changing the parameter to `isSpace` and `notSpace` from `char` to `unsigned char`. This way you won't get completely broken behavior when the user enters characters with accents, umlauts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool f()
{
    return 2;
}
int main()
{
  cout <<f()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

it will print 1 when you return 2, that's why you get the warning.
someone may think a bool is kind of small integer, but it isn't.

If you go back to C, there was no `bool` type, that's why many C methods (like `isspace`) returns `int`, even WINDOWS type of `BOOL` is actually kind of integer and can return other values but `TRUE` (1) or `FALSE` (0).